# How to alias a command containing both apostrophes and quotation marks?

Tags: shell, command-line, quoting, alias

As a result of my previous question I decided to

`alias groe= ?vim -c 'normal "+p1Gdddd"' -c ':%s/\n/' -c 'normal"gVGgJy"' -c'q!'?`

I cant find out how to substitute '?s' in my example to make it work.
Already tried question marks and apostrophes. Any Ideas would be appreciated. Thx

Comment: Try using hard (single) quotes for the question marks and then escaping the inner hard quotes with backslashes (`\'`). Maybe you also need to escape the backslash to work or escape both to make an escaped quote (i.e. `\\'` or `\\\'`). This depends on how nested the whole thing is. Better pretest your alias by just `echo`ing it. Douple quotes within single quotes should be fine.

Answer (score 7):

"Inside" single quotes you could have a single quote by closing the outer single quote, then add an escaped single quote and re-open the outer single quotes, like

```
echo 'It'\''s ugly.'
```

In other words all `'` will become `'\''` plus outer single quotes.

Your alias would look like that:

```
alias groe='vim -c '\''normal "+p1Gdddd"'\'' -c '\'':%s/\n/'\'' -c '\''normal"gVGgJy"'\'' -c'\''q!'\'''
```

Or you could use C-style escapes `$'...'` where you have to escape single quotes only once but also escape character in `\n`:

```
echo $'It\'s a newline: \\n'
alias groe=$'vim -c \'normal "+p1Gdddd"\' -c \':%s/\\n/\' -c \'normal"gVGgJy"\' -c\'q!\''
```

Comment: Fantastic. It worked, but I it needed one more escape before '\n' to escape newline in the middle of the command ( or is it rather an expression?)

Comment: Hm for me it seems work, see echo 'It look'\''s \n ugly.' I'll add another version using C-sytle escapes.

Comment: Yes you are right, it works in Bash. I tend to use Z shell and in it  fails ( as well as in tcsh)..

Answer (score 7):

Make it a shell function, so you can lose the outer quotes.

```
groe() {
  vim -c 'normal "+p1Gdddd"' -c ':%s/\n/' -c 'normal"gVGgJy"' -c'q!' "$@"
  }
```

That should call `vim` with the arguments `-c`, `normal "+p1Gdddd"`, `-c`, `:%s/\n/`, `-c`, `normal"gVGgJy"`, `-cq!`. The `"$@"` at the expands to the parameters you gave to the function, so `groe foo.txt` should work.

Comment: Yes, that worked for me too, but isn't it general rule that if you can contain command in one line you should use alias, otherwise define function?

Comment: This solved my problem, but with Ubuntu 20.04 I had to define the funcion as `function groe()`

Answer (score -2):

On MacOS I found that placing the following line in my `.bash_profile` gave me an alias that only setup my useful alias upon later usage of the `logr` command:

```
alias logr="alias r='java -jar LogUtil.jar -gui'"
```

I used double quotes `""` around the entire `logr` alias that gets created for all new shells, but then the `r` alias only becomes available once I issue the `logr` command.

Comment: Since your alias does not contain double quotes, it's ok and correct to do this. Note that the user in the question has a command that includes both single quotes and double quotes.